# Error de Sonarqube Asegúrese de deshabilitar Angular incorporado sanitización

Tags: javascript, angular, sonarqube

Tengo actualmente este código para poder visualizar una imagen, pero cuando solo subo a SonarQube me arroja este error Make sure disabling Angular built-in sanitization is safe here.

**este es el service.ts**

```
public getImagen(id: number):Observable<Blob>{
  return this.httpCliente.get(`${this.hostApiOnDemand}/uploads/img/${id}`, {responseType: 'blob'})
}
```

**este es el compoents.ts**

```
  this.apiodService.getImagen(id).subscribe({
    next: (blob) => {
     let objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
     this.mostrarImagen = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(objectURL)

   }});
```

**este es el html**

```
   <img [src]="mostrarImagen" class="img-thumbnail rounded">
```

**les comparto una imagen del error de SonarQube:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

sí saben cómo solucionar este error se lo agradecería enormemente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según la [documentación](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer), para las imágenes deberías ocupar `bypassSecurityTrustUrl`, ya que dice:

> Omita la seguridad y confíe en que el valor dado sea una URL de estilo
> seguro, es decir, un valor que se pueda usar en hipervínculos o .<**img**
> src>

En cambio `bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl` dice que son para `iframe` y `script`

```
  this.apiodService.getImagen(id).subscribe({
    next: (blob) => {
     let objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
     this.mostrarImagen = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(objectURL)

   }});
```